# Remove duplicate from an array in js with condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove duplicates id present in array. Duplicate id should be removed keeping its  maximum count. For Example -

My object contain following properties:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "count": 10
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "count": 3
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "count": 6
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "count": 15
},{
    "id": "2",
    "count": 12
}]
```

Explanation:
id : 2 is duplicate so I need to remove id : 2 having count 10 and 12. I need to keep id have the maximum count.

I didn't find any similar question so was unable to solve it. I'm a beginner in js so comments in code would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use array.reduce to achieve this. Refer https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just iterate over each value and evaluate if it's the max in your accumulated collection:

```js
let unique_set = {}
let arr = [{
  "id": 2,
  "count": 10
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "count": 3
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "count": 6
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "count": 15
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "count": 12
}]

arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.id in unique_set) {
    if (unique_set[obj.id].count <= obj.count)
      unique_set[obj.id] = obj;  // update
  } 
  else
    unique_set[obj.id] = obj;    // create
});

console.log(Object.values(unique_set))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const source = [{
    "id": 2,
    "count": 10
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "count": 3
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "count": 6
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "count": 15
},{
    "id": "2",
    "count": 12
}]
let result = []

source.forEach(sourceItem => {
    let found = false
    result.forEach(resultItem => {
        if (resultItem.id == sourceItem.id) {
            resultItem.count = Math.max(resultItem.count, sourceItem.count)
            found = true
        }
    })
    if (!found) {
        result.push(sourceItem)
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to iterate all over the array, you can get the result by using the following code snippet:

check it on https://jsfiddle.net/pramodsingh/py7hax4o/19/

```js
var obj = [{
    "id": 2,
    "count": 10
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "count": 3
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "count": 6
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "count": 15
},{
    "id": "2",
    "count": 12
}];

let max = Math.max.apply(Math,obj.map(function(o){ return o.id == 2
&& o.count;}));

let result = obj.filter(function(o){
 return !(o.id == 2 && o.count != max);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `reduce` and `Object.values` will simplify

```js
const update = data =>
  Object.values(
    data.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => (
        (acc[curr.id] =
          curr.id in acc
            ? { ...acc[curr.id], count: Math.max(acc[curr.id].count, curr.count) }
            : { ...curr }),
        acc
      ),
      {}
    )
  );

const data = [
  {
    id: 2,
    count: 10
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    count: 6
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    count: 15
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    count: 12
  }
];

console.log(update(data));
```